# how to enabled app links menu in android setting

Tags: android, react-native

I am developing a app with react-native.

On my test device, when I enter the app info menu as shown below, there is an Open by default menu, but the APP LINKS menu is disabled. I would appreciate it if you could tell me how to enable it.

Settings > Apps & notifications > App info > MyApp > Open by default
([device capture image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/agQDI.png))

Below is the AndroidManifest.xml code.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<application
  android:name=".MainApplication"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
  android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
  android:allowBackup="false"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
  <uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false"/>
  <activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    </intent-filter>
  </activity>
</application>
```